# Optimal number of models?

Tags: r, machine-learning, supervised-learning

Say I have to predict a response variable having 4 levels 1,2,3,4 which account for respectively 78%, 5%, 16%, 1% number of observations. I have two options:

1. Build one classifier to predict 4 levels at the same time
2. Build 2 models, the first one predict the level (1) against levels (2,3,4). The second classifier predict the levels 2,3,4 based on the result of the previous classifier.

The reason for the second model is that: it can resolve the problem of unbalanced data when the distribution of levels will be ~ (22%,73%,5%).

Which option is theorically better?

Comment: Don't be so afraid of class imbalance, just assign different weights to instances of different classes (a ratio of 78:1 doesn't necessitate drastic measures like using exotic classifier hierarchies). You are overcomplicating this. You can start worrying about class balance when one class has 99.9% or more of all instances.

Comment: it's just illustrative numbers, what if I face the situation where we have imbalanced data (80,15,4.9,0.1)?

Comment: Like I said, weigh instances of minority classes higher to even out the cost function across classes. If your modelling approach doesn't allow this by design, then a very simple yet surprisingly effective way is to just duplicate samples of your minority class.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: I more or less agree with you, but does the second approach harm the performance in a theoretical point of view?

Comment: Depends on the learning method. If you're using powerful methods that *learn* structure like (deep) neural networks or random forests , then yes, because you are effectively giving the second level classifier less data to learn from. You also introduce potential performance dependencies in unintuitive places, since the overall performance of your scheme depends largely on the first classifier (even for levels 2, 3, 4!). Suppose you have low recall for level 1 in classifier 1, what do you do with those seeping level 1's in classifier 2 (problem: they are not part of any of its known targets)?

Comment: @MarcClaesen what if we have the "perfect" first classifier with the accuracy ~ 99%?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best result will come from building 3 binary logit models separately and using them together with the logistic regression formula.

Model 1: Y=1 for the 2's, Y=0 for the 1's, drop all others 
Model 2: Y=1 for the 3's, Y=0 for the 1's, drop all others
Model 3: Y=1 for the 4's, Y=0 for the 1's, drop all others

Now that each model produces estimates to build a logit the estimated probability is calculated like:

P(Y=2)=e^logit1 / (1+e^logit1+e^logit2+e^logit3)

After the others are calculated, P(Y=1) = 1-P(Y=2)-P(Y=2)-P(Y=3)

I believe this will yield the best result, especially if some independent variables are strong versus 1 response but not the others.